# How to install Firebase Crashlytics Swift 3.0

Tags: swift3, crashlytics, google-fabric

i am working swift 3.0 version  project .. i want to install   Firebase Crashlytics but, pod have only latest .. how to install swift 3.0  Firebase Crashlytics pod or manual framework. thanks

Comment: Have you seen [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started)? There is a section "Add frameworks manually" that seems to be what you are after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please install below pod for firebase crash analytics.

```
 pod 'Crashlytics', '3.12.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample way is to read documentation, they explained already.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started